# How do you make an algorithm that will return the number of elements in an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I already have some code that I think is going in the right direction, but need help filling in the gap. Please be aware that I cannot use array.Length here and I actually have to make a algorithm that will perform the same function as array.Length. Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static int size(int[] S, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            (S[i] 
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is _int n_ supposed to be?

Comment: It's taken from the size of the array. The size of the array is 5, but we need a variable to pass 5 into, rather than just hardcode the amount of times we require the loop to occur.

Comment: the number of elements in array is `Length` (`S.Length` here)

Comment: If `n` is the size of the array, then.... `return n`?

Comment: We can't use S.Length, the point is I need to code the actual algorithm itself.

Comment: It's really not clear, what `n ` is supposed to be. If you only need to return the size of `int[] S`, why would you need some other value?

Comment: If you are *really* asking about the length of an array, there is no algorithm. An array actually has a property with the number of items it contains, unlike C/C++ where there's no way to know the actual size of an *array*. Strings or STL containers are different cases.

Comment: @parkie1995 what do you mean by the number of elements? The length is a property of the array assigned during creation, there is no algorithm involved. Either the question is a misunderstanding and should be closed, or you are asking for something else

Comment: Poorly expressed questions. Consider revision.

Comment: Poorly expressed indeed. It seems the function is of the form: "for an arbitary memory address, how big is it?"

Comment: I am pretty sure this is homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very silly assignment as C# arrays provide their length using the `Array.Length` property. I think you should make this clear in your delivery.

However, to stay within the rules try this:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
int count = 0;

// iterate all elements in the array
foreach(int item in array)
{
    count++;
}

// count will equal 10
return count;
```

Comment: This will work with any IEnumerable and I think that's how `Count()` works if the input enumerable doesn't implement `IList` as arrays do. Perhaps the assignment mentioned enumerables instead of arrays?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want the sum, rather than the number of elements, in which case the following should suffice:

```
public static int size(int[] S, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += S[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you actually wanted the number of elements in the array, use this:

```
public static int size(int[] S, int n)
{
    return S.Length;
}
```

Although I do not understand why you would need this (since n is already the length of the array) you can do the following:

```
public static int size(int[] S, int n)
{
    int length = 0;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int i2 = S[i];
            length++;
        }
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {
    }
    return length;
}
```

If this still doesn't answer your question please take some time to rewrite it in a way we can actually understand what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I want the number of elements in the array not the sum. And I cannot use S.Length as I actually have to code a function that will find it out.

Comment: @parkie1995 But you said `n` already **is** the number of elements in the array. So what do you need to calculate?

Comment: @parkie1995 the question doesn't make sense. Arrays don't *calculate* their size, they actually have a property with it.

Comment: @Thealon, solution to what? C# already has the `algorithm` for counting the elements, I don't understand what this solves?

Comment: You guys don't understand. This assignment is all about making algorithms. Rather than using a built in function of C#, I had to show that I can make some code that will do what .Length does.

Comment: Ok fine but what's the point of variable n then?

Comment: @parkie1995, the reason we **Don't Understand**, is that you've left this important piece of detail out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the `int n` does; would this work?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            count = i + count;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: This way `count` is the sum of the indices that appear in the array...